# Forwarding and printing messages from multiple clients with sockets in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, client-server

I know there is a lot of post with titles similar to this one. Most of them have no answers or just answer how to respond to one client not multiple. Ive been bashing my head for sometime with this code. I know for sure that recieving connections  and adding them to a list is working. My problem is when I try to print messages from the clients o screen. One client works fine, you can his messages on screen, the problem comes whith more than one client. When the second client connects you cant see his messages on the server side, after some messages from the first client, the messages sent from the second client appear. So I know for sure the messages are being recieved, the problem is with the printing.

server script:
    import socket,sys
    from threading import Thread

```
prevcon=0
buffsize=1024
connections=[]
addreses=[]
try:
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

except socket.error as e:
   print ("Failed to create a socket")
   print (e)


host="192.168.0.103"#raw_input("Enter Target host here: ")
port=12345#raw_input("Enter Target port here: ")

try:
    s.bind((host,int(port)))

except socket.error as e:
    print ("Failed to Connect")
    print (e)

s.listen(5)
s.setsockopt( socket.SOL_SOCKET,
socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1 )


def listen_connections():
        while True:
            #print ("waiting for connection")
            client_sock, addr = s.accept()
            connections.append(client_sock)
            addreses.append(addr)
            print ("client connected from: ",addr)


def print_messages():
    while True:
        for i in range(0,len(connections)):
            try:
                data=connections[i].recv(buffsize)
            except socket.error:
                print ("User Disconnected from: ",connections[i])
                connections[i].close()
                del connections[i]
                del addreses[i]
                continue
            print (data.decode("utf-8"))
            print (connections)
            #send_message(data,i)

    s.close()

def send_message(data,pos):
        for connection in connections:
            if connection!=connections[pos]:
                connection.send(data)



if __name__=="__main__":
    thread1=Thread(target=listen_connections)
    thread2=Thread(target=print_messages)
    thread1.daemon=True
    thread2.daemon=True
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
```

client script:

```
    import socket,sys
from threading import Thread

try:
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

except socket.error as e:
    print ("Failed to create a socket")
    print e

host="192.168.0.103"#raw_input("Enter Target host here: ")
port=12345#raw_input("Enter Target port here: ")

try:
    s.connect((host,int(port)))

except socket.error as e:
    print "Error Connecting"
    print e

print ("Connected to host: %s and port: %s" %(host,port))

def leer():
    while True:
        data=s.recv(1024)
        print data.decode("utf-8")


def send():
    while True:
        payload=raw_input("Enter here text to send: ")
        s.send(payload)

if __name__=="__main__":
    t1=Thread(target=leer)
    t2=Thread(target=send)
    t1.daemon=True
    t2.daemon=True
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

Comment: Is this really your exact code? I can't imagine this code working. Both threads you start are daemons, and the main thread exits immediately. Basically the programs start up and then immediately shut down again.

Comment: @Rawing yeah that its my exact code

Comment: small code tag / indentation problems, please correct.

Comment: @FedericoAgudeloMejia You have put `python-3.x` tag on your question, but the code indicates Python 2.x from the contained print statements. What is intended?